# How to set character in accumulo?

Tags: accumulo

I use the accumulo shell to inspecte tables.I find I can insert english,But When I insert Chinese,I see some garbled in shell .how to deal with this problem.Can I set utf-8 in Accumulo?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no. Unfortunately, displaying UTF-8 characters is not currently possible. Accumulo primarily deals with raw bytes, not Strings of Characters. The shell currently (up to 2.0.0-alpha-2, at least) has very limited capabilities to display wide Unicode characters. The shell's behavior is to, for convenience, show printable 7-bit ASCII characters; the rest are shown as hex-encoded form.

While the current shell capabilities are limited, it is an open source project, that would welcome patches to better support any UTF-8 printable characters.

Comment: Thanks,I want to use Accumulo store raster and vector and use geoserver publish data.The vector contain some Chinese features，I don't know how to deal with this proplem.

Comment: You can store bytes of any type you wish. Accumulo treats everything as byte arrays. You just won't be able to use the shell to do much of the work. The shell is primarily intended for triage, and very basic system administration tasks. For anything else, you should use the Java API directly.